# How to move 2 selected faces to other side of object

Tags: edit-mode, mirror, duplicate

Blender beginner here. I want to move 2 selected faces seen on this image to other side of object but can't figure it out and find an answer.

I tried to mirror these but in this case it mirrors everything including the small handle which I don't want to happen. I tried to duplicate everything and removing handle but in that case I am left with 2 holes on the side of object. I also tried to duplicate vertices in the beginning but those did not attach to main object.
Does anyone know what would be a good solution here?

[image]

After making it symmetric or mirroring I have 2 holes on side

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: separate parts that you don't want to mirror

Comment: I have handle separated but when I mirror it still mirrors the holes under the handle I think

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx.

Comment: Here is my file https://blend-exchange.com/b/lKpy8gd5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way (without using the *Mirror* modifier) is to use the *Mesh > Symmetrize* tool (and choose the axis in the *Operator Box*), but you'll have to remove the handle once done:

[image]

Comment: How can I invert it? Suddenly it symmerizes the wrong side and window holes(selected faces on image) dissapear.

Comment: make sure that the origin is at the center of the symmetry and also check the axis in the Operator Box (bottom left of your 3D view), see my edit

Comment: Yes that's helpful. However for me it leaves 2 holes because I have handle already separated. I'll leave edited image.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: If you have a hole you can simply fill the hole, not sure about the subdivision though, why do you need so many faces?

Comment: I just didn't know a better way to create a handle there that's why I did the subdivision with an idea to dissolve them later. 

Here is a blender file https://blend-exchange.com/b/lKpy8gd5

Comment: just fill the hole and remove all these faces with X > Limited Dissolve. Your handle can be a separate mesh within the same object. It can also be part of the same mesh if necessary, you just need some edge loops, you don't need such a high poly surface